# MvxSpinner Initial Value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-spinner

I have an MvvmCross `MvxSpinner` binding in Android.  The user selects a value and that gets reflected in my property `MealTypeSelected`.

```
<MvxSpinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MealTypeList;SelectedItem MealTypeSelected, Mode=TwoWay" />
```

The spinner is to allow the user to select the meal type (breakfast, lunch, dinner, etc).  The meal type is represented by an Enum called `MealType`.

`public enum MealType {Unspecified, Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Snack};`

I want to make it easier on the user by initializing the spinner to a value based on the time of day when the `ViewModel` is shown.  So if the page is loaded at noon, I'll guess that the selection should be "Lunch" for example.

The problem is, I have tried setting the `MealTypeSelected` property in the `ViewModel` at different locations of the life cycle: constructor, `Init`, and `Start`.  But regardless of what I do, when the View loads, it changes the selection **back** to the default value of the Enum, which is the value "Unspecified".

Is there a way around this behavior and have the `MvxSpinner` initialized to specific value?

Comment: From what I recall, the spinner auto selects the initial value in its ItemsSource. You could init the ItemsSource for the Spinner to have the first index be the specific MealType for the time of day.

Comment: That worked but now my spinner list is "Lunch, Unspecified, Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Snack" when the user clicks on it.  I guess I could do some custom layouts to clarify but it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow won't let me accept pnavk's comment as an answer but it is what I ended up doing.  Each time the user selected something, I would change the first item to the list to what was selected.  An ugly solution but it worked.  If that's not acceptable to others, it looks like you might have to do some custom binding.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your "Setup.cs" file. I had the same struggle, and this worked for me. Cant remember where i found the solution the first time.

```
    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
```

Comment: I have tripped up on that issue in the past as well, but fortunately already had that in my Setup.cs.  The binding doesn't work at all unless you have that.  In my case, the binding is working but I am unable to set the initial selection to anything other than the first value of the List.

Comment: Could you try to update the question with the properties in your viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when binding the SelectedItem of an MvxSpinner to my ViewModel, while also setting it in the ViewModel.

Overriding the `Equals` of the type that I was binding to fixed this problem.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return this.Id == (obj as MyType)?.Id;
}
```

Since you seem to be binding directly to an enum, you might have to try and wrap it in another object.

Comment: This is the real answer. Reorder the list is a workaround.